# Make Font Awesome positioned right to list text

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

thanks in advance,
I'm trying to make font awesome to be positioned to the right of my text in a  list. I'm using A RTL language hope someone could help couldn't find nothing regarding this.

**I'm using Divi theme**

**my text will be aligned to the right and I want the icon to be in the right as well**

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
   <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
   <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
   <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: which type of output you need

Comment: @ozherez I've updated my answer. Please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move icon after text...

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
   <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i></li>
   <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i></li>
   <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i></li>
```

Comment: Thank you  so much , total appreciation my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your code to this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square" style="position:static"></i></li>
  <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square" style="position:static"></i></li>
  <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square" style="position:static"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , total appreciation my friend really helpful :))

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Change code just move after text:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square" style="position:static"></i></li>
  <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square" style="position:static"></i></li>
  <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square" style="position:static"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , total appreciation you guys are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position: initial` to icon.

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/2706/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
   <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i></li>
   <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i></li>
   <li>List icons<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.fa-ul .fa-li {
  position: initial;
}
```

Comment: Thank you  thanks you so much , total appreciation you guys not just super you are both super duper :)